# What does Q*Bert say when he dies?

Tags: video-games, languages, q-bert

When the classic Q*Bert character dies, he says something that sounds like an alien language:

[image: Q*Bert die]

What is he supposed to be saying, exactly?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

According to the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q%2abert) on Q*Bert:

> [Audio engineer David] Thiel was tasked with using the synthesizer to produce English phrases for the game. However, he was unable to create coherent phrases and chose to string together random phonemes. Thiel also felt the incoherent speech was a good fit for the "@!#?@!" in Q*bert's speech balloon.

Comment: Given that there's speech found elsewhere in the game (including complex multi-syllable speech like "**Hello**", "**I'm Turned On**", "**Bye-Bye!**") this answer makes no sense.

Comment: https://youtu.be/HKIbhaQfs-A  to hear "hello, i'm turned on."  Not exactly coherent.

Comment: Well, I can certainly understand what he's saying.

Comment: @Valorum - So...you say that this being incoherent makes no sense, then post an answer saying essentially the same thing?

Comment: @JohnP - The principle is that a [grawlix](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/grawlix) covers up bad language. It's still reasonably clear what the meaning and intent are, even if the specifics are lost.

Comment: @Valorum - Question - "What is Q*Bert saying?" Kyle - "Incoherent speech" Valorum "Garbled nonsense". Same answer, and neither references grawlix.

Comment: @JohnP - I didn't write the manual, go yell at them :-)

Comment: Clearly, QBert is saying "Laurel" :-)

Comment: @JohnP - I believe Valorum's point is that there are other phrases in the game that don't really sound like "incoherent speech." The quote in the answer would lead one to believe that all of the verbalizations in the game are random phonemes strung together. I wont say it's impossible that the power of imagination and suggestion lead us to believe that the other phrases are coherent (after all, I'm not sure I ever heard the "plugged in" or "bye-bye" sounds), but it doesn't seem like all the speech was random noise.

Answer (score 20):

According to the [original game manual](http://www.gamesdatabase.org/Media/SYSTEM/Arcade/Manual/formated/Q-bert_-_1982_-_Gottlieb.pdf) (describing the process of installing your arcade cabinet), when Q*Bert is killed he emits

> ***"Garbled Nonsense Speech".***

---

[image]

Answer (score 10):

Long story short, he's rudely cursing his fate.

The nonsense characters in the word balloon are known as "[Grawlix](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/grawlix-symbols-swearing-comic-strips)", a term coined by Beetle Bailey creator Mort Walker, and are used in comics to denote sour language. The "garbled nonsense speech" is the game's own version of bleeping out the bad words. Cartoons will also use nonsense sounds to cover up the bad words, like the dolphin calls in Spongebob's "Sailor Mouth" to cover the sentence enhancers.

> "One of the most unique aspects of Q*bert was its implied swearing
>   when players sent poor Q*bert to his doom. What he's actually saying
>   has never been revealed, but I'm sure anyone would curse their luck if
>   a snake knocked them off a floating pile of blocks."

Kotaku - [A Brief @!#?ing History Of Swearing In Video Games](https://www.kotaku.com.au/2014/06/a-brief-ing-history-of-swearing-in-video-games/)

Comment: Do you have a source for this? The game manual seems to disagree.

Comment: The grawlix in the word balloon are a universal symbol in comics, and the link is one of many descriptions of the term and its origin. The game manual describes it as garbled nonsense, and tactfully does not specify that it's a stand-in for bad words. It doesn't mean any SPECIFIC curse words, nor does almost any use of the symbols, unless used in association with LeetSpeak, as in "$#!+"

Comment: You said in comics, sure, that does not mean it has the same intentions in Qbert. Unless you have evidence, I see no reason to believe that is the case.

Comment: "One of the most unique aspects of Q*bert was its implied swearing when players sent poor Q*bert to his doom. What he's actually saying has never been revealed, but I'm sure anyone would curse their luck if a snake knocked them off a floating pile of blocks. " - A Brief @!#?ing History Of Swearing In Video Games - https://www.kotaku.com.au/2014/06/a-brief-ing-history-of-swearing-in-video-games/

Comment: "The character Q*bert became known for his "swearing", an incoherent phrase of synthesized speech generated by the sound chip and a speech balloon of nonsensical characters that appear when he collides with an enemy." - Wiki entry -  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q*bert

Comment: There you go, evidence. No need leaving it in the comments when it can be in the post.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, are you aware of some use of the grawlix where it DOESN"T mean implied swearing that caused you to so vehemently question the reference?

Answer (score -4):

I think he is saying "oh crap" or "bad luck" as I have searched it up many times and it sounds like something he would say as "@!)*&@" means hello in his language.

Comment: Welcome to SFF! This seems to contradict the accepted answer so may not be true. However, if you have any evidence to back up your claims this would be a good answer! Therefore, I encourage you to [edit] them in.